# If I say "Well you have yourself a good bank Holiday" and they reply "Yeah" and don't turn round. Are they rude?

Tags: politeness, conversation

If I say "Well you have yourself a good bank Holiday" and they reply "Yeah" and don't turn round. Are they being rude?

A co-worker had their back to me. I said this as a way to say Bye. They responded "Yeah"

Comment: What’s the context/culture? Who are they to you, outside of being a co-worker; do you like them, do you actually work *with* them? What country are you in? And, lastly, why do you want to know/why does it matter; what are you going to do if it turns out they were rude?

Comment: Hi Five to you Fivesideddice - The person is not English.  I wish to know is there any way this could be read as an appropriate response.  The person was working and I respect a person carrying on with their work.  However a "You too" would I believe be the appropriate minimal response.

Comment: How is that an ELL question?

Comment: @JackO’Flaherty we do have the politeness tag for a reason — although admittedly it generally deals with the opposite case, where the asker worries that they haven’t been polite.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with English. Instead, it's entirely open to speculation and subjective opinion.